# How to associate document files with MS Office 2010 Beta?

Tags: microsoft-office, office-2010-beta

I've installed MS Office 2010 Beta (OneClick technology). All apps launch from 1 program, Word for example has this link:

> `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Virtualization Handler\CVH.EXE" "Microsoft Word 2010 (Beta) 2014006204190000"`

Or OneNote:

> `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Virtualization Handler\CVH.EXE" "Microsoft OneNote 2010 (Beta) 2014006204190000"`

Because of that I can't associate files with Office programs in file properties, they actually associate with “Microsoft Office Client Virtualization Handler” (CVH.EXE).

Anyone know another way to do that?

Comment: Final release have no problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the 64-bit version installed? It looks like the files were installed in the x86 program files directory, which only exists on 64-bit Windows. There's a 64-bit version of the Office beta available. It's possible that would work better.

If you already have the 64-bit edition, try this. It should work:

Choose which document type you want to set this for. Set it to open CVH.EXE. Open the registry editor. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx` (for example - replace `.docx` with whichever extension applies). See what the REG_SZ value (Default) is set to. By default it will be something like `Word.Document.12`, but it may be something different on your system. Then, go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\command` (replacing Word.Document.12 with whatever the value was you got from the last step). Edit the REG_SZ value "default" to whatever you want the command to be; in your case, probably `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Virtualization Handler\CVH.EXE" "Microsoft Word 2010 (Beta) 2014006204190000" %1`. (`%1` is the filename which you are opening)

That should work! If it doesn't, I'll see if I can come up with any other ideas.

Comment: It seems like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\command` does not belong to `.docx` (if i change command in registry, file is still opening with old program; if I change program in file properties, nothing changes in this registry item). `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docx` default field shows `Word.Document.12` and file has `.docx` extension.

Didn't find where can I download 64-bit version. On microsoft.com I downloaded X16-NNNNN_CCCCC-CCCCC-CCCCC-CCCCC-CCCCC.exe (N - number, C - number or letter), I wasn't asked to choose version.

Comment: It depends on where you download it from. I downloaded it from TechNet, where there is an option to choose. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/ee390818.aspx, click on "Get Started Now", log in, then select the 64-bit download. This may work better for you overall anyways. 

What is associated with the registry entry mentioned? What is currently opening .docx files?

Try searching in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key for the name of the executable you set the word docs to open with - the handler application. Does it appear anywhere?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I've created an empty .com file (unique_name.com on desktop) and associated .docx with it. I found something interesning in HKEY_CURRENT_USER. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.docx\UserChoice` contained `unique_name.com`. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\unique_name.com\shell\open\command` contains full path to program `"C:\Users\Sema\Desktop\unique_name.com" %1`. All Office apps launch from one .exe with different parameters, I think it is impossible to separate each extension to open exe with it's own parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows 7 OS.  I managed to fix it by simply going to Control Panel/Uninstall Program,  right clicking on MS Office and choosing the "change" option, this then performed a "repair" of the application and the association issue was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this answers you question, but i had a similar problem of not being able to alter my default program settings for ms office programs, like you mention due to the virtualisation handler. 
Instead of fiddling in my registry i chose to get rid of the virtualisation handler. To do so you have to deinstall and instaal some office programs, see detailed instructions at:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/office2010/thread/0d2708ec-13d8-41dc-a62a-32792975801b
hope this helps.